# Remove loaded script from runing dynamic web page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a script from my running web page. I did it as mention on the previous problem. It doesn't work me. How I remove loaded script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>
<script src="aa.js" type="text/javascript"  id="ht"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.er').click(function(){
        $("script[src='aa.js']").remove();
    });
});


</script>


<input type="button" class="btns" value="Alert" /> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="er" />
```

Followed this methods. But wasn't success

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

[jQuery - dynamically remove head elements on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611895/jquery-dynamically-remove-head-elements-on-click)

Comment: What behavior were you expecting, and what actually happened? Removing a `script` element from the DOM doesn't actually unload the functional code that was executed when the script loaded. All of the script's variables and functions are still loaded into memory.

Comment: Yesa I know that. I want remove it from memory too. How should I do?

Comment: Simple answer? You can't do it easily. If you know what the script does, you can construct your script to iterate over the object it creates and delete them. So, if a script creates a function called `foo()`, your removal script would have to do something like `delete window.foo;`, and repeat that action for every object created by that script. There may be something deeper in the internals that will let you reflect on the origin of a member object, but I'm not aware of any such method.